# Why, using Newton's method for approximating roots, do distances have quadratic relationships?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, newton-raphson

[This MIT lecture](https://youtu.be/4Q37iOyBq44?t=5m) defines $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}, \forall n\in\mathbb N$, where $x_1$ is a reasonable first guess for the root of the curve in the video. It then explains how $|x_a-x_{n+1}|^2\sim|x_a-x_n|$, where $x_a$ is the actual root. Could anyone explain why it is so?

Comment: A rough argument to see why it is so: Taylor expand $f$ about the zero $x$ ($f(x)=0$) in the numerator and denominator. To first order the equation then becomes $x_{n+1}-x \approx \frac{f''(x)}{2f'(x)}(x-x_n)^2$

Comment: @Winther I haven't learnt about Taylor facts yet. Do you have an idea what the person in the video briefly explains (5:00-6:10 of the video)? He makes it sound like a simple argument (and says it is), but I couldn't quite understand what he meant.

Comment: A Taylor series to order $n$ about a point $x_0$ is an approximation to $f$ that matches the function value and the first $n$ derivatives at that point. In formulas  $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2 + \ldots $. If we are close to the point $x_0$ then just including the first few terms in the expansion above is enough to get a good approximation to $f$. This expansion insterted into the formula and neglecting small terms is enough to see that we get quadratic convergence. To prove this one needs to be a bit more rigorous.

Comment: Even less rigorous: The derivative is the best linear approximation of a function, so $f(x+Δx) = f(x) + f'(x)\cdotΔx + \mathcal{O}(Δx²)$, where $\lim\sup\frac{\mathcal{O}(Δx²)}{Δx²}$ is finite (thus, “the error is quadratic”).